# How do I add/remove selected column(s) in a JTable?

Tags: java, swing, jtable, tablecolumn

I am currently able to just add a column to the last column, and remove the last column added.

I am trying to figure out how to add or remove a selected column but its just not working out for me.  For example if I have 3 columns 0, 1, and 2, and I want to add a column to 1 or remove column 1.

I spent an hour in the library but the most I was able to get done was removing and adding row to selected place.

Can someone please help?

This is what I have for adding column but it does not do what i want (only adds to the end):

```
String colName = Integer.toString(i++);
        if (colName != null && colName.length() > 0) {

            model.addColumn(colName);
            table.updateUI();
            undo.push(new Object[]{"Column", "Add", colName});
            redo.clear(); 
        }
```

Comment: _most I was able to get done was removing and adding row to selected place_ contradicts with your question

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To add a column at an arbitrary index, use the table column model's `addColumn()` followed by `moveColumn()`:

```
TableColumn newColumn = // ...
colModel.addColumn(newColumn);
colModel.moveColumn(colModel.getColumnCount() - 1, desiredIndex);
```

Removing a column at an index should be even easier:

```
colModel.removeColumn(colModel.getColumn(desiredIndex));
```